# Misplaced label mixing list environments

Tags: formatting, lists, memoir, dramatist

I am hacking the [`dramatist`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dramatist) package. My aim is to get speech-prefixes to align with speeches for the verse environment, as they do for the prose environment. I've got it working except for a problem with the first speech prefix being misaligned.

Manually expanding all the macros for the MWE with what I currently have gives this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
\begin{list}{}{}

Enter Bob and Mike

\item[Mike] Hello
\item[Bob] Hello
\item[Mike] Bye!
\item[Bob] Bye!

\end{list}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

This causes the first "Mike" prefix to be positioned over the first "Bob" prefix.  The result is

[image: here].

I know that the verse environment from memoir is implemented as a list, so I assume that the problem is to do with interactions between their list customizations.

The reason for wanting to have the plain text (a stage direction) inside the `list` is so that the `list` can be defined once for the whole document. (This is how `dramatist` works for prose.)

The same problem occurs with the standard `verse` environment instead of that defined by `memoir`.

I'd be very grateful for any advice on how to avoid this. I am new to LaTeX, so general advice on how I might diagnose the problem myself would be useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @david-carlisle for the hint about plain text in lists causing problems.

I'm going to go for this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
\begin{list}{}{}

\item\begin{quote}\em Enter Bob and Mike\end{quote}

\item[Mike] Hello
\item[Bob] Hello
\item[Mike] Bye!
\item[Bob] Bye!

\end{list}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Which creates:

[image: this]

Answer (score 4):

Everything in a list environment should be prefixed by `\item` or things go badly wrong as you show. If you move the line before the list things look better

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
Enter Bob and Mike

\begin{list}{}{}
\item[Mike] Hello
\item[Bob] Hello
\item[Mike] Bye!
\item[Bob] Bye!

\end{list}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

But I don't know if that is the alignment you want?